# Rollover to be loaded with the index page and disappears when iframe is loaded with content from a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm having a small issue with iframe and rollover image.

What I want to achieve is when I load this index site it should display a rollover image(or a slider later on once I know how to do it) in the middle of the page. I have placed an iframe in the middle of this index page. This iframe is going to be the target of the horizontal menubar...

How do I make them to co-exist, rollover to be loaded by default and disappears once the iframe is loaded with content from a link?

I have tried to place a rollover inside the iframe and also now inside the same div of the iframeBut the result is not good since the rollover image is not disappearing when loading a link to the iframe:

```
<div><center>
<a href="recipes/casserole/Sunday Brunch Casserole Registered.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','recipes/exps10761_TH10059C8.jpg',1)"><img src="recipes/exps1330_TH2028C39D.jpg" alt="Casserole" width="300" height="300" id="Image1" /></a>
<iframe name="content" width="1400" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></center>
</div>
```

Index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home Of Recipes</title>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>
<body background="food2_indx.jpg" onload="MM_preloadImages('recipes/exps10761_TH10059C8.jpg')">

<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<div><center>
<a href="recipes/casserole/Sunday Brunch Casserole Registered.htm" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','recipes/exps10761_TH10059C8.jpg',1)"><img src="recipes/exps1330_TH2028C39D.jpg" alt="Casserole" width="300" height="300" id="Image1" /></a>
<iframe name="content" width="1400" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></center>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized a much more simple solution. 
-Just create a separate page of the rollover images rollover.html
-Preload iframe with src="rollover.html".

When you want to load the url, just give it the target of the iframe name and it will load the url content to that iframe and the rollover will no longer be displayed.

In my case target="content"

```
<center>
<iframe name="content" src="rollover.html" width="100%" height="1280" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</center>
```